# How do I check divisibility in Java?

Tags: java, division

I am trying to check if on number is divisible by another, and currently I use this method:

```
int x = 70;
int y = 30;

if(x/y == Math.round(x/y)) {
    ...
}
```

Is there a simpler way?

Comment: `if (x%y == 0)`

Comment: Perform an additional check for `y == 0` and don't (try to) divide if the condition is `true`...

Comment: ignoring 'simpler' for a second, your method doesn't even work because of how integer division works in Java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use modulus operator like this in your condition,

```
if (x%y == 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

A good way is to use modulus operator, which returns the remainder after dividing by a number, e.g.

```
5 % 2 = 1 (1 is the remainder after 5 is divided by 2)
```

So for a number to be divisible by another, it should have a remainder of 0 (i.e. x % y = 0)

```
if (x % y == 0)
{
  //x is divisible by y
}
else
{
  //x is not divisible by y
}
```